# trying to change the functions of a string

Tags: python-3.x

I wrote this code so that the user could input a sentence and then be given a list of options to choose to edit their sentence or check if things are true. I am trying to make it loop until the user says no to seeing another function, but I'm not sure how to do it.

How can I make it so that the user can decide whether or not to continue seeing the list?

```
def main():
  global string
  string = str(input("Write a sentence with both numbers and letters: "))
  print("There are many different options when it comes to string functions")
  print("Here is a list of options that you can use to edit your sentence:")
    title()
    lower()
    upper()
    islower()
    isupper()
    isspace()
    count()
    strip()
    replace()
    decimal()
    alpha()
    numeric()
    swap()

def title():  
  title = input("would you like to change the first letter of each word to UPPERCASE?")
  if title == "yes":
    print(string.title())

def lower():    
  lower = input("Would you like to change all characters to lowercase?")
  if lower == "yes":
    print(string.lower())

def upper():
  upper = input("Would you like to change all characters to UPPERCASE? ")
  if upper == "yes":
    print(string.upper())

def islower():
  islower = input("Would you like to check if your sentence is all lowercase? ")
  if islower == "yes":
    print(string.islower())

def isupper():
  isupper = input("Would you like to check if your sentence is all UPPERCASE? ")
  if isupper == "yes":
    print(string.isupper())

def isspace():
  isspace = input("Would you like to check if your sentence is only spaces? ")
  if isspace == "yes":
    print(string.isspace())

def count():
  count = input("Would you like to count the number of 'a' letters that are in your sentence? ")
  if count == "yes":
    print(string.count("a"))

  isdigit = input("Would you like to check if your sentence is all digits? ")
  if isdigit == "yes":
    print(string.isdigit())

def strip():
  strip = input("Would you like to take out the spaces before and after your sentence? ")
  if strip == "yes":
    print(string.strip(" "))

def replace():
  replace = input("Would you like to replace 'a' with 'X' in your sentence? ")
  if replace == "yes":
    print(string.replace("a", "X"))

def decimal():
  decimal = input("Would you like to check if your sentence is all decimals? ")
  if decimal == "yes":
    print(string.isdecimal())

def alpha():
  alpha = input("Would you like to check if your sentence is all letters from the alphabet? ")
  if alpha == "yes":
    print(string.isalpha())

def numeric():
  numeric = input("Would you like to check if your sentence is made up of numbers? ")
  if numeric == "yes":
    print(string.isnumeric())
def swap():
  swap = input("Would you like to swap the uppercase letters with the lowercase letters? ")
  if swap == "yes":
    print(string.swapcase())


main()
```

Comment: you can use an input what the user wants to see and then check what the user wants

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user enters anything other than "no", your main() function runs again.

```
exit = ""
while(exit != "no"):
    main()
    print("See options again?")
    exit = input()
```

Comment: Where would I put that?

Comment: After you define the function, so replace that main() at the end with this code

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using a boolean flag?

Something like `displayList = True` at the start of the program. Then if they input that they don't want to see the list anymore, `displayList = False`, then wrap the list in

```
if displayList:
    print("list details")
```

so that it only displays when `displayList` is true.

Comment: Where would I put that in my program?